# HTML-- Give fieldSets some structure on page

Tags: html, css, jsp

Im iterating over a list to create fieldsets on the page. the last fieldset is at the bottom left and it looks crazy Is there something I can do to my layout to make these fieldSets look decent on the page?

[image]

html:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>

    <td width="50%" align="center">

    </td>
 </tr>

 </table>

     <table class="data_table" width="100%">

  <tr>
        <th>
            <span onclick="toggleDiv('displayFields', 'displayImg')" style="cursor: hand;">Data Fields&nbsp;<img name="displayImg" src="../images/minus.gif" /></span>
        </th>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>


            <div id="displayFields" style="display:block;">

                <c:forEach items="${detFieldMap}" var="detFieldEntry">     
                    <fieldset class="det">         
                        <legend>${detFieldEntry.key}</legend>  

                            <c:forEach items="${detFieldEntry.value}" var="detBean">            
                            <input type="checkbox" name="fieldNames" value="${detBean.fieldName}">${detBean.displayName}</input>            
                              </br>    
            </c:forEach>     
            </fieldset> 
            </c:forEach>

            </div>
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="button" name="clear_choice"  value="Check All" onclick="checkUncheck(true);"/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="button" name="clear_choice"  value="Uncheck All" onclick="checkUncheck(false);"/>

            </td>
            </tr>

        </td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
/*css. */
table.det
{
}

 table.det td
 {
 border: none;

 }
/* This groups small (16x16) icons using a border and a label. */
fieldset.det 
{     
display:block;
float:left;

font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:20px;
border:2px solid #CCCCCC;

}
 fieldset.det legend
{
    padding:2px 5px;
    border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
    font-weight:  bold;


}
```

Comment: Really ambiguous. You can style fieldsets with CSS like any other element.

Comment: "look decent" is ambiguous and subjective. What exactly do you want it to look like?

Comment: How would you have them to look like then? Note that your HTML table syntax is invalid. You can't have a `<tr>` as direct child of `<td>`.

Comment: at least not have the last one in the bottom left sticking out like that

Comment: Is the position of the funding data one the problem? It can only be being put there by some code somewhere, so it's more of an issue with existing code than needing some new code. (Is far as I know.)

Comment: maybe 2 rows of fieldsets?...at least that last one wont be alone....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all `<fieldset>`s in a single table row `<td>` next to each other in different table columns `<td>`s, then you should be putting each one in **its own** `<td>`. This way the table layout is maintained.

E.g.

```
<table class="data_table" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="${fn:length(detFieldMap)}">
            <span onclick="toggleDiv('displayFields', 'displayImg')" style="cursor: hand;">Data Fields&nbsp;<img name="displayImg" src="../images/minus.gif" /></span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="displayFields">
        <c:forEach items="${detFieldMap}" var="detFieldEntry">     
            <td>
                <fieldset class="det">         
                    <legend>${detFieldEntry.key}</legend>  
                    <c:forEach items="${detFieldEntry.value}" var="detBean">            
                        <input type="checkbox" name="fieldNames" value="${detBean.fieldName}">${detBean.displayName}</input>            
                        </br>    
                    </c:forEach>     
                </fieldset> 
            </td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="${fn:length(detFieldMap)}" style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="button" name="clear_choice"  value="Check All" onclick="checkUncheck(true);"/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="button" name="clear_choice"  value="Uncheck All" onclick="checkUncheck(false);"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I also fixed your invalid HTML of nesting a `<tr>` as direct child of a `<td>`. Use http://validator.w3.org to nail down HTML syntax errors yourself.

Comment: BalusC...are you a oracle or something?

Comment: BalusC I still need them divs for the Onclick at the top

Comment: Oh, assign it to the `<tr>`. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: thank BalusC...tried that but the fieldsetd came out all chopped up. What about just modifying the CSS?...maybe the fieldset properties?

Comment: Im playing with the Table width now